# Load from file latitude longitude into Google Maps API (not an array or MVC array error)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to recreate a Google Maps heatmap listed on the developer website [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap). In their example they load multiple latitude/longitude coordinates in an array that is written into the code.

I want to load coordinates from a file. I've searched and seen many examples of this but can't get it to work with this specific heatmap example. I keep getting a "not an Array or MVCArray" error and I feel like I'm missing something simple.

See the loadPoints and getPoints functions below. One is loading from an external file and gives an error. The other loads from the array and works fine.

```
<script>

  var map, heatmap, dataarr;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: {lat: 37.775, lng: -122.434},
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: loadPoints(), // Gives "not an Array or MVCArray" error, but getPoints() works fine
      map: map
    });
  } 

  function toggleHeatmap() {
    heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
  }

  function changeGradient() {
    var gradient = [
      'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
      'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
      'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
      'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
      'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
      'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
    ]
    heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
  }

  function changeRadius() {
    heatmap.set('radius', heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 20);
  }

  function changeOpacity() {
    heatmap.set('opacity', heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2);
  }

  function loadJSON(file, callback) {   

      var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
      xobj.open('GET', file, true);
      xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
              callback(xobj.responseText);
          }
      };
      xobj.send(null);  
  }

  function loadPoints() { 
      loadJSON("data.php", function(response) {
          var data = JSON.parse(response);

          dataarr = []
          for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
              dataarr.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lon))
          }
          //return dataarr
          console.log(dataarr)
      });         
  }

  function getPoints() {
    return [
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782919, -122.442815),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782992, -122.442112),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783100, -122.441461)
    ];
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your file is loaded asynchronously but you're trying to synchronously set the data, so it's gonna be undefined. You may need to rethink your structure a little, but one solution is to wait until the data is loaded before setting your heatmap. Or just move initMap into your asynchronous callback. 
[Check this SO question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/8237835)

Comment: Thanks, that put me on the right path. I ended up finding  [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps) Google developer page that allowed me to solve the problem.